# Chosen JQuery - Limit X selectable per Optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have 10 optgroups some with 80-100 options and some with 2-3, i need a way of only allowing X amount selectable for each optgroup and then hiding the rest of them.

I have a large amount of data so i wont copy and paste it. Its a bunch of arrays in an object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    eachTitle();
})

function eachTitle() {
    let titleCount = Object.keys(data).length;
    for (var i = 0; i < titleCount; i++) {
        let dataTag = Object.keys(data)[i];
        $(".tagging-select optgroup." + dataTag).append(
            data[dataTag].map(data => {
                return $("<option/>", {
                    value: data,
                    text: data
                })
            })
        )
    }
    initaliseSelect();
}

function initaliseSelect() {
    $(".tagging-select").chosen({
        no_results_text: "No results found",
        display_selected_options: false,
        display_disabled_options: false,
        include_group_label_in_selected:true
    })
}
```

I have optgroups like this -

```
<select class="tagging-select" multiple data-placeholder="Select Option">
        <optgroup label="Difficulty" class="difficulty">

        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Age" class="age">

        </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have data like this -

```
var data = {
    difficulty: [
        "Easy",
        "Average",
        "Hard"
    ],
    age: [
        "Adult (17 and over)",
        "Paediatrics (0-16)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: the reason why you show all is because you map all of the data, but you want to map only "X" quantity... so modify your function to map only "X": elements by looping only on "X" of the elements... keep in mind to check if the data contains less than "X" elements, so it loops on "X" or `data.length` iterations....

Comment: Thats not what i mean, from each optgroup I want to only select X amount. For age I want to only be able to select one and for difficulty i may want to select 2 etc..

Comment: then [select multiple](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) is what you may be looking for

Comment: Sadly not - I have a multi select using the Chosen Jquery plugin but under each Optgroup I want to limit how many can be selected under each setting to X

Comment: You could listen to the event onChange on the select element and keep an array of the options selected then if the array.length is > "X" display a message "you have reached the maximum selections for this item" or something like that, it will work without the array just by counting the selected items...

Comment: Hey Diego, got it partially working - not perfect but a working example. So i should be good for now. Sadly it wasnt as easy as doing what you said above as the plugin makes it a whole lot more difficult

Comment: I'm glad, hope you narrow the details. You could share your solution as a response to help others. good coding.